# Why can't I use <template> as an angular2 component template?

Tags: javascript, templates, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

**Update**

Apparently when using `<template>` the reading of `innerHTML` will return all attributes in lower case. Angular2 will not understand `ngfor` or `ngif` as of this beta 9 version and throws error. `<script>` is treated as a text fragment rather than DOM, which means attributes stay as they are.

Here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/yz-XdYV2vYw

**Originial**

Taking the following html and angular2 beta 9 component:

**HTML CODE**

```
<my-page>Loading...</my-page>

<script type="text/html" id="my-component-template1">
    <select [(ngModel)]="SelectedType">
        <option *ngFor="#someType of MyTypes" [selected]="SelectedType == someType" [value]="someType">{{someType}}</option>
    </select>
</script>

<template id="my-component-template2">
    <select [(ngModel)]="SelectedType">
        <option *ngFor="#someType of MyTypes" [selected]="SelectedType == someType" [value]="someType">{{someType}}</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

**JS CODE**

```
    var myComponent =
        ng.core.Component({
            selector: 'my-page',

            //complains if i use #my-component-template2
            template: document.querySelector('#my-component-template1').innerHTML 
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function () {
                var self = this;

                self.MyTypes = ['first', 'second'];
                self.SelectedType = self.MyTypes[0];
            }
        });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(myComponent);
    });
```

If i use `my-component-template1` it works fine, but if i choose `my-component-template2` it complains that `ngModel` and `ngForOf` are not a known native properties.

I tested a `div` as a template and apparently that won't work either with the same errors. So question is, why is it breaking if the template is part of the DOM? Furthermore, I really don't want to use the `script text/html` hack. Assuming this is why `<template>` was added in html5 specification. Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular handles `<template>` tags itself and doesn't simply add them to the DOM. If you inject `TemplateRef` into the constructor of your component you should get a reference to the template.

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private tmplRef:TemplateRef) {

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using ES6, so how does this translate in existing JS? `Template` is a mandatory field for the component definition which is executed before the constructor.

Comment: This is the same for ES6 or TS. Not sure what you mean by "`Template` is a mandatory field". If you mean the `template` parameter of the `@Component(select: 'xxx', template: 'yyy')` decorator, this parameter and the use of a `<template>` tag are not related at all. `TemplateRef` is a type and a token for DI which results in getting a reference to a `<template>` element injected like `@Query()`

Comment: My questions doesn't relate to injection, but usage of `<template>` as an actual template for a component. Getting a reference to it is not an issue, but the parsing is. Check my update.

Comment: What's the actual use case? What do you try to accomplish. I don't understand what you mean by "as an actual template for a component".

Comment: Every component needs a template. This is mandatory and provided differently in ts or ES6 than ES5. Example in my question is trying to use html5 <template> element for an angular2 template, which doesn't work. My update explains why it doesn't work.

Comment: Using a `<template>` as template for a component is just not supposed to work. The template a component needs is not related to the `<template>` tag as I already mentioned. The name equality is accidental.

Answer (score 2):

The `<template>` tag **is only used** by Angular 2 [structural directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#template) (like the built-in ngIf, ngFor, ngSwitch, etc) - its use is somehow similar with the [html5 specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) since it defines content which is stored for subsequent use.

The `*` in front of a structural directive is just syntactic sugar which allows us to skip the `<template>` tag and focus directly on the HTML element that we are including, excluding, or repeating - you can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template).

**An example from Angular 2 docs which showcases this:**

```
<!-- Examples (A) and (B) are the same -->
<!-- (A) *ngIf paragraph -->
<p *ngIf="condition">
  Our heroes are true!
</p>

<!-- (B) [ngIf] with template -->
<template [ngIf]="condition">
  <p>
    Our heroes are true!
  </p>
</template>
```

At the moment, I'm not sure if there's a way of defining inline Angular 2 HTML templates like there's in AngularJS 1. Your *hack*, as you put it, seems to do its job.

Comment: Every hack does its job, but we should follow standards and try not to hack our way around. Meanwhile, my google discussion revealed the problem. Check my update.